# MySQL Stop Insert based on field value

Tags: mysql

I want to do an insert ignore if a column has a specific value.

Say I have a simple table that records changes to a PO over time. Each time the PO is updated, I need to insert a record on this table:

```
PONum | POLine | submittedBy   | ... other columns 
100     1        initial-value
100     1        TB
100     2        initial-value
```

On a PHP page I check for the existence of the PO number in this table. If there isn't one, I insert all the PO lines I find from another table. I set the submittedBy name to "initial-value".

Now later on, say PO Line 3 is added. I want to run through my check again and only insert the new record for line 3 if there isn't already one that has line 3 with a submittedBy of *initial-value*

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO PODetailCL (PONum, POLine, submittedBy, ... )
VALUES (100, 1, 'TB', ... ),
(100, 2, 'TB', ...),
(100, 3, 'initial-value', ...)

WHERE submittedBy <> 'initial-value' -- <- something like this but not sure of the syntax
```

Comment: `something like this but not sure of the syntax`Have you tried this? This looks absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a virtual column and then add a unique constraint on that column. After that I can use INSERT IGNORE. (Virtual columns are only available in MySQL version 5.7 or later.)

```
ALTER TABLE porelcl 
ADD COLUMN initialCheck BIT GENERATED ALWAYS 
           AS (CASE WHEN submittedBy = 'initial-value' THEN b'1' ELSE NULL END)
```

then after that:

```
ALTER TABLE porelcl ADD UNIQUE initial_check_index (PONum, POLine, PORelNum,  initialCheck)
```

Now when my code runs through the check again, if tries to insert a duplicate record: SomePO, SomePOLine, SomePORelNum & 'initial-value'  the insert won't take place, which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO PODetailCL(PONum, POLine, submittedBy, ... )
    SELECT (100, 1, 'TB', ... ), (100, 2, 'TB', ...),(100, 3, 'initial-value', ...)
        FROM PODetailCL
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PODetailCL WHERE submittedBy <> 'initial-value')
```